# Gamestream accellerated VNC application?

Tags: vnc, streaming, gpu, gaming

Steam currently has it's in-home streaming solution in he beta install of the application. This tech lets you stream your game over a VNC-like protocol to local devices but uses hardware encoding on your server machine to reduce latencies massively and relieve your CPU and GPU from the ailments that seriously harmed your framerate.

It seems these GPU encoders are massively underused elsewhere. Is there any applications out there that would allow me to stream using a VPU to encode without restricting things to one application, say like VNC but with a much better framerate and still maintaining full GPU acceleration?

Comment: I would also like to know if it's possible to gamestream your windows desktop, as I find Splashtop interesting but could be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Add an application, whatever application you're using most, to Steam's Library. I added OpenScad, others have added Chrome, Notepad.exe or even Explorer.exe.

From inside a Streaming OpenScad session, on my mac, I use Option + Esc to see the desktop.

It's less than perfect, but it works pretty well. For my purpose it's a huge timesaver!

[Steam] -> [Games] -> [Add A Non-Steam Game To My Library] -> [Select or browse to your app of choice]